# Can I install a sink that drains into this floor drain?

Tags: plumbing, sink, drainage, building-regulations

I would like to install a sink in my basement but the only drain that is close to it is being used for the HVAC. Can I use this existing drain for the sink as well?

This is roughly how the drain is currently setup/used. 
[image]

Comment: do you mean draining your sink onto the floor? or breaking up the concrete and tying into this drain line?

Comment: Draining it into the floor. Last resort would be tying into the line if that's possible.

Comment: It looks like there is a drain stack right next to your water heater, could you not tie in here?

Comment: Not saying it's right or wrong, but my local Costco store does the same thing with the drain on their drink machines.  It's not connected to a drain in the wall, just a pipe running into a floor drain.

Comment: The picture is not of my own setup. I just found a picture of a similar floor drain.

Comment: Many jurisdictions wold not allow you to drain a sink into a drywell (I assume that is what the floor drain is connected to).

Comment: The floor drain is about 10 feet from the main sewer line (the hole in the floor that pumps stuff into our septic). If it is connected to it, can I use it?

Comment: Before anyone can answer your question, you need to find out what your floor drain is connected to (sanitary sewer, storm sewer, etc.) as that will drastically impact what options you have. If you have schematics, you're in luck, if not, you may need to contact a plumber to have them come scope out the pipes. Typically you cannot put waste from a sink into a storm sewer. If it is purely water (no chance of soap, etc.) as in the case of air conditioner drain lines, then some localities have additional flexibility.

Comment: If it is connected to the Sewer system, can I use it then?

Comment: @Hooplehead24 If the floor drain connects to the sanitary sewer (not storm sewer), then there shouldn't be any issue draining into it with a 2" air gap per most plumbing codes, but each locality ultimately decides what is acceptable. If you want to tie into the line without an air gap, you would need to make sure proper venting is in place to prevent sewer gases from entering your home.

Comment: In the midwest United States, I can think of a dozen houses (built 1896-recently) off the top of my head that have some type of shop sink or washing machine in their basement that just pipe their waste to the floor drain.  It is almost universal that these drains feed into the sanitary sewer stack around here.  Although in rural areas, things are always a bit "different" due to less regulations.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ask your local building inspectors.  Some places allow grey water drainage into their overflow drain but most don't.

One of the problems you will have is if your sewer backs up it will back up into your sink drain.  This isn't a huge deal but could get messy.  Also you would be require to secure the PVC to the floor in some way.

I personally don't see an issue with it.  There is no real downside other than it looking slightly ghetto.  Most inspectors would just tell owner to set it up after they pass inspection - hence most cities won't recognize it as finished plumbing.  Will it work though, sure as long as you are not sending a ton of mud or crap down your sink.

Answer (score 1):

New construction single family houses, floor drains are connected to the sewer, individually vented when it’s not a emergency drain. Sink discharging into a floor drain no longer makes it an emergency drain so it should be vented. Mn third year plumber… not the best yet but I’m in school.

Answer (score 0):

Floor drains often go to small sumps for diffusion into the soil, since they're just intended to handle occasional spills. For more volume, or for anything you wouldn't want your back-yard garden soaking up, you really want a proper drain connection.

(The pipe is for condensate, which is fairly clean and fairly small amounts.)

Comment: The drain is fairly close to the sewer system. If I find out it drains into that, is it ok to use it for a bar sink?

Answer (score -1):

No.  You cannot do that.  It is against all rules of common sense, the national building codes of Canada and the US, and almost surely against the local plumbing ordinances you have.  A sink needs to be connected to your sanitary sewer.  The floor drain will be connected to your storm sewer.  If you are in an older home, where they are shared, you could do it, but you will have to excavate the floor and make the connection sub-slab with rigid connections and not flexible hose or pipe.  If you don't do it properly, you could end up having a flood in the basement, or having sewage or storm water or both coming into the basement and not having any way out.

Comment: My floor drain connects to my sanitary sewer. Major metro upper midwest USA.